# bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, requirejs-config.js, bootstrap4

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and I'm working on jquery. I load some minified js files including bootstrap 4 alpha 6 and tether.min.js but facing some errors in loading tether.min.js. Please help if anyone has an idea of this.
Below is error which I get in my console-
[image]
bootstrap.min.js:7 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)
at bootstrap.min.js:7:3482
at bootstrap.min.js:7:12271
at bootstrap.min.js:7:14333

**This is my requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            tether: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/tether.min',
            bootstrapjs: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/bootstrap.min',
            formbuilderminjs: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/form_builder.min',
            jqueryui: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/jquery-ui.min',
            jqueryjs: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/jquery.min',
            formbuilderjs: 'Training_HelloWorld/js/form_builder',
        }
    }
};
```

**Below is my phtml code where I call these js files**

```
<script >
    require(['jquery', 'tether','bootstrapjs','formbuilderminjs','jqueryui','jqueryjs','formbuilderjs'],
            function($)
    {
        
    });
</script>
```